# Catching UnpermittedParameters in complete rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, strong-parameters

We are adding strong params, and the application is quite large. So there is a possibility that we would have missed some parameters from permitting.

So, to track such cases, how can I catch UnpermittedParameters error/warning throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this in `development.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

This way it would be pretty clear an error happened. You'd still have to check your endpoints though.